Docker APT repositories no longer work on Mint 22
I recently upgraded to Mint 22 from 21.3, and I had to purge docker, and it's repository for the mitnupgrade script to work. Now I'm back to installing all the stuff I had to remove for the upgrade, and the docker engine (Docker-ce) doesn't seem to have a release file for this version.
Just to make sure I tried following these tutorials:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository
and
https://www.huuphan.com/2024/08/how-to-install-docker-on-linux-mint-22.html
Which seem to produce the same result where when I try to update with APT, I get:
Err:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu wilma Release       
  404  Not Found [IP: -.-.-.-]
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu wilma Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

What am I supposed to do differently from the installation method for earlier distro versions?

The instructions on the Docker website generate an APT source file that uses your distro codename, which is Wilma for LM 22, but you want to use the repo for the version of Ubuntu that LM Wilma is based on, Noble.
Edit your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list file, and change https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu wilma stable to https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu noble stable
This is covered in the official instructions,

If you use an Ubuntu derivative distribution, such as Linux Mint, you may need to use UBUNTU_CODENAME instead of VERSION_CODENAME

but it's easy to miss that footnote
